# How can I split an ArrayList<String> into 2 more ArrayList<String> with a ratio of 1:5

Tags: java, arraylist

I am trying to split an ArrayList called **mainarray** into two other ArrayList's

- ArrayList called **array1**
- Arraylist called **array2**

In the **mainarray** I have **exactly** 12 values:

- "1"
- "2"
- "3"
- ...

How can I split them up so there are 2 random values in **array1** and 10 random values in **array2**

Thank you for your help!

Comment: it's not clear. You have exactly 10 values ?

Comment: Maybe you should show some code :)

Answer (score 1):

Just get two random values from one list and add to another.

```
Random r = new Random();
list1.add(mainarray.remove(r.nextInt(10)));
list1.add(mainarray.remove(r.nextInt(10)));
list2.addAll(mainarray);
```

Comment: But I want to have 2 values in array1, and 10 values in array2.

Comment: So just get random values and don't remove.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `mainarray.size()` to find the size of your main ArrayList.

if you want the ratio to be 1:5, there will be 6 total divisions. so use two `for` loops: one with a range of **1 to size/6**, the other with a range of **(size/6)+1 to 6*(size/6)**.

In your example there are 12 elements in your array, so this method will give you 1 and 2 in your `array1` and 3 to 12 in your `array2`.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll try that.

Comment: Or rather 0-1 and 2-11, as indexes to `mainarray`. Result won't be random, but you could call [`Collections.shuffle(mainarray)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle%28java.util.List%29), copying `mainarray` first if it should be left unchanged.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this:
This code select from ArrayList `numbers` select 2/10 element2 to add at `head` and add 10 elements at `tail`:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) 
  {
   List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
   numbers.add(3);
   numbers.add(4);
   numbers.add(5);
   numbers.add(6);
   numbers.add(7);
   numbers.add(55);
   numbers.add(32);
   numbers.add(555);
   numbers.add(1);
   numbers.add(55);

   List<Integer> head = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        List<Integer> tail = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for(int i = 1; i<=numbers.size(); i++){
            if(i%6==0){
                head.add(numbers.get(i-1));
            }
            else{
                tail.add(numbers.get(i-1));
            }
        }
        System.out.println("head: "+ head); 

        System.out.println("tail: "+tail); 

        System.out.println("numbers: " +numbers); 
     }
```